# import module error in fastapi am importing from the nested routers ,its showing the error attribute error module not found error in that file

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, uvicorn

[When I try running  uvicorn app.main:app, it's showing the error even all the modules routers have the **init**.py even tried by giving export PYTHONPATH=$PWD won't be worked, my folder structure as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwOxB.png)

[this is the follder struture of fastapi project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpbFP.png)

[this is the follder struture of fastapi project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMU4Z.png)

Comment: please click on the wordings to see the error image

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see here for [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)